# Agora Voice chat is unable to join chat on unity windows build installer version

Tags: agora.io

agoraSdkCWrapper
Fallback handler could not load library D:/APPNAME/Data/Mono/agoraSdkCWrapper.dll

The voice chat SDK is working fine in unity editor and even the .exe file is running normal.

But as soon as I covert the .exe file to a installer using inno setup compiler,
and install the application through the installer on the computer,
when I use the installed .exe file ,
the voice chat freezes and never connects on pressing the join channel button.

Please help me identify the loophole,
is there any special permission we need to request on windows ?
I have windows 10,64 bit

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the whole Inno set up on Windows but I successfully ran the installed voice test demo.

Please check your Inno Setup file to include the exact sample directory structure and files in your Unity build folder.

Comment: I fixed it 
Actually the X86 option was unchecked in plugin/agoraSdkCWrapper.dll in unity

So I just reimported it in unity and and checked the option